# Expected value of Y=min(X,1-X)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, uniform-distribution

**Problem:** Random variable $X$ has uniform distribution over $[0,1]$ and $Y=\min(X,1-X)$. Prove that the expected value of $Y$ is $\frac 14$.

**Attempted Solution:**
I start by finding the CDF:

$F_Y(x) = P(Y<x) = 1 - P(\min(X,1-X)>x) = 1 - P(X>x)P(1-X>x)$

Then by finding $P(X>x)$ and $P(1-X>x)$ , I could calculate the derivative of $F_y(x)$ and thus find the PDF of $Y$. Is this the right approach?

Also is $P(X<x)$ equal to $1-x$?

Comment: $ P(min(X,1-X)>x) =  P(X>x)P(1-X>x)$ is wrong because $X$ and $1-X$ are not independent.

Comment: Read Dilip Sarwate's comments in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724648/expected-length-of-a-stick-broken-into-two-pieces-explaining-the-length-funct?noredirect=1&lq=1). Someone else could have written the same as an answer, I'll try to find it. I'm also wondering why you want to find $F_Y$ unless you've been asked to find it : you can just use LOTUS as written up [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/350863/316409). A good search phrase for this question is : "length of shorter piece of uniformly broken rod".

Comment: $\min\{X,1-X\}= X\,\mathbf 1_{X\leq 1/2}+(1-X)\,\mathbf 1_{X>1/2}$ so if you did want it $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(\min\{X,1-X\}\leq x) &=(\mathsf P(X\leq x)+\mathsf P(X\geq 1-x))\mathbf 1_{x < 1/2}+\mathbf 1_{x\geq1/2}\\&=(2x)\,\mathbf 1_{0\leq x< 1/2}+\mathbf 1_{1/2\leq x}\end{align}$$